# detecting NVIDIA GPUs without CUDA

Tags: c, cuda

I would like to extract a rather limited set of information about NVIDIA GPUs without linking against the CUDA libraries. The only information that is *needed* is compute capability and name of the GPU, more than this could be useful but it is not required. The code should be written in C (or C++). The information would be used at configure-time (when the CUDA toolkit is not available) and at run-time (when the executed binary is not compiled with CUDA support) to suggest the user that a supported GPU is present in the system.

As far as I understand, this is possible through the driver API, but I am not very familiar with the technical details of what this would require. So my questions are:

- What are the exact steps to fulfill at least the minimum requirement (see above);
- Is there such open-source code available?

Note that the my first step would be to have some code for Linux, but ultimately I'd need platform-independent code. Considering the platform-availability of CUDA, for a complete solution this would involve code for on x86/AMD64 for Linux, Mac OS, and Windows (at least for now, the list could get soon extended with ARM).

**Edit**

What I meant by "it's possible through the driver API" is that one should be able to load libcuda.so dynamically and query the device properties through the driver API. I'm not sure about the details, though.

Comment: Have you considered the [Tesla Deployment kit](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/tesla-deployment-kit) (which includes source code examples of the queries you mention, but has some limitations) ?

Comment: @RobertCrovella I have, but I don't really like the idea of distributing binaries. What are the other drawbacks?

Comment: Which binaries are you referring to that you need to distribute?  libnvidia-ml.so gets installed by the nvidia driver (if it's a "recent" driver).  So without trying to cover everything in a comment, the limitations are: 1. requires an appropriate, "recent" nvidia driver be installed, 2. may not provide as much info on GeForce products as it does on Quadro and Tesla GPUs (although this is partly a GeForce limitation, for example no ECC support).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is building without the Cuda toolkit a no-no.  Because this is literally the simplest thing ever with it.

Comment: There is a deviceQueryDrvAPI example in the CUDA samples included with the CUDA SDK (and starting with CUDA 5.0, included with the CUDA Toolkit distribution).  This shows you how to query what you need with the driver API. But all of the suggested solutions require "linking against the CUDA libraries". I suspect you just mean you don't want to link against the CUDA runtime API library (cudart), because that would require you to distribute the cudart shared lib.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I was referring to the libnvidia-ml.so library, I didn't realize that it was included all recent drivers. However, nvml can not provide an essential information: compute capability.

Comment: @8bitwide: simply because if a binary is not compiled with CUDA is ran on a machine with a GPU, I want to be able to tell the user that it might be worth considering recompiling.

Comment: @pszilard The best I've been able to come up with is to check the gpu model with directx or Opengl and compare that against a known list.  This of course is not optimal.  As far as I can tell, Nvidia doesn't expose any cuda API's outside of the sdk, leaving you with two options.  Rip the countcudedevice() function out of the sdk(may just be a couple of headers and dll's) or do some serious research and write your own implementation.

Comment: @8bitwide Maintaining a list of GPU names is the hell I want to avoid -- been there, done that and users kept on asking why is my brand new GPU not supported. I'm pretty pissed at NVIDIA for not enabling compute-capability information with nvml.

Comment: @pszilard At this point, the simplest solution seems to be not to allow any binaries to be compiled without the Cuda sdk, You don't have to include all your Cuda code in the binary, but at least the part that checks for Cuda capability.

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately NVML doesn't provide information about device compute capability.

What you need to do is:

1. Load CUDA library manually (application is not linked against libcuda)

   - If the library doesn't exist then CUDA driver is not installed
2. Find pointers to necessary functions in the library
3. Use driver API to query information about available GPUs

I hope this code will be helpful. I've tested it under Linux but with minor modifications it should also compile under Windows.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef WINDOWS
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <dlfcn.h>
#endif


void * loadCudaLibrary() {
#ifdef WINDOWS
    return LoadLibraryA("nvcuda.dll");
#else
    return dlopen ("libcuda.so", RTLD_NOW);
#endif
}

void (*getProcAddress(void * lib, const char *name))(void){
#ifdef WINDOWS
    return (void (*)(void)) GetProcAddress(lib, name);
#else
    return (void (*)(void)) dlsym(lib,(const char *)name);
#endif
}

int freeLibrary(void *lib)
{
#ifdef WINDOWS
    return FreeLibrary(lib);
#else
    return dlclose(lib);
#endif
}

typedef CUresult CUDAAPI (*cuInit_pt)(unsigned int Flags);
typedef CUresult CUDAAPI (*cuDeviceGetCount_pt)(int *count);
typedef CUresult CUDAAPI (*cuDeviceComputeCapability_pt)(int *major, int *minor, CUdevice dev);

int main() {
    void * cuLib;
    cuInit_pt my_cuInit = NULL;
    cuDeviceGetCount_pt my_cuDeviceGetCount = NULL;
    cuDeviceComputeCapability_pt my_cuDeviceComputeCapability = NULL;

    if ((cuLib = loadCudaLibrary()) == NULL)
        return 1; // cuda library is not present in the system

    if ((my_cuInit = (cuInit_pt) getProcAddress(cuLib, "cuInit")) == NULL)
        return 1; // sth is wrong with the library
    if ((my_cuDeviceGetCount = (cuDeviceGetCount_pt) getProcAddress(cuLib, "cuDeviceGetCount")) == NULL)
        return 1; // sth is wrong with the library
    if ((my_cuDeviceComputeCapability = (cuDeviceComputeCapability_pt) getProcAddress(cuLib, "cuDeviceComputeCapability")) == NULL)
        return 1; // sth is wrong with the library

    {
        int count, i;
        if (CUDA_SUCCESS != my_cuInit(0))
            return 1; // failed to initialize
        if (CUDA_SUCCESS != my_cuDeviceGetCount(&count))
            return 1; // failed

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            int major, minor;
            if (CUDA_SUCCESS != my_cuDeviceComputeCapability(&major, &minor, i))
                return 1; // failed

            printf("dev %d CUDA compute capability major %d minor %d\n", i, major, minor);
        }
    }
    freeLibrary(cuLib);
    return 0; 
}
```

Test on Linux:

```
$ gcc -ldl main.c
$ ./a.out
dev 0 CUDA compute capability major 2 minor 0
dev 1 CUDA compute capability major 2 minor 0
```

Test on linux with no CUDA driver

```
$ ./a.out
$ echo $?
1
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, this is starting to look promising! Now the only issue is that this code includes cuda.h and my very goal is to compile such a small piece of code at configure-time, check for compatible hardware, and warn the user if found anything useful. So it is assumed that the CUDA toolkit is not installed on the host machine. I've found a cuda_drvapi_dynlink_cuda.h in the SDK. Lifting the required code from that would, I guess, do the job, the only thing I need to figure out is the licensing (which has to be LGPL compatible).

Comment: Can't you just ship this application as a binary? It can be compiled with just C compiler so you won't hit any CLI incompatibility issues like with C++ (CUDA runtime API requires C++ compiler but not CUDA driver API). I'm not sure where the requirement of compiling this app at configure-time is coming from.

Comment: No, I can't. This is a scientific HPC code that is compiled on pretty much all hardware from netbooks to the largest supercomputers. An important aspect is avoiding a dozen error messages the user has to work around (including on missing CUDA toolkit) and only warn the user if there's a supported device detected at configure- or at run-time.

Comment: What I meant is can't you ship an application that searches for CUDA devices as a binary. It can be compiled with gcc and will work on any machine without any need for recompilation. Just run this discovery app during configure step.

Comment: On Windows 10, I did not require the cuda.h include and the above example worked.

Comment: ( ... but the types CUresult and CUdevice needed defining)

Answer (score 1):

Sure these people know the answer:

http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer

but i can only know that i could be done with an installation of CUDA or OpenCL.

I think one way could be using OpenGL directly, maybe that is what you were talking about with the driver API, but i can only give you these example (CUDA required):

http://www.naic.edu/~phil/hardware/nvidia/doc/src/deviceQuery/deviceQuery.cpp

Answer (score 1):

First, I think [NVIDIA NVML](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/nvidia-management-library-nvml) is the API you are looking for. Second, there is an open-source project based on NVML called [PAPI NVML](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/).

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in an above comment, NVIDIA NVML is not a good candidate because AFAIK it does not provide information on compute capability. I'll have a look at PAPI NVML, though, but I suspect that it won't provide this information either.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using and linking statically against the CUDA 6.0 SDK. It produces an application that works also well on a machines that does not have NVIDIA cards or on machines that the SDK is not installed. In such case it will indicate that there are zero CUDA capable devices.

There is an example in the samples included with the CUDA SDK calld *deviceQuery* - I used snippets from it to write the following code. I decide if a CUDA capable devices are present and if so which has the higest compute capabilities:

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

struct GpuCap
{
    bool QueryFailed;           // True on error
    int  DeviceCount;           // Number of CUDA devices found 
    int  StrongestDeviceId;     // ID of best CUDA device
    int  ComputeCapabilityMajor; // Major compute capability (of best device)
    int  ComputeCapabilityMinor; // Minor compute capability
};

GpuCap GetCapabilities()
{
    GpuCap gpu;
    gpu.QueryFailed = false;
    gpu.StrongestDeviceId = -1;
    gpu.ComputeCapabilityMajor = -1;
    gpu.ComputeCapabilityMinor = -1;

    cudaError_t error_id = cudaGetDeviceCount(&gpu.DeviceCount);
    if (error_id != cudaSuccess)
    {
        gpu.QueryFailed = true;
        gpu.DeviceCount = 0;    
        return gpu;
    }

    if (gpu.DeviceCount == 0)
        return gpu; // "There are no available device(s) that support CUDA

    // Find best device
    for (int dev = 0; dev < gpu.DeviceCount; ++dev)
    {
        cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
        cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);
        if (deviceProp.major > gpu.ComputeCapabilityMajor)
        {
            gpu.ComputeCapabilityMajor = dev;
            gpu.ComputeCapabilityMajor = deviceProp.major;
            gpu.ComputeCapabilityMinor = 0;
        }
        if (deviceProp.minor > gpu.ComputeCapabilityMinor)
        {
            gpu.ComputeCapabilityMajor = dev;
            gpu.ComputeCapabilityMinor = deviceProp.minor;
        }
    }
    return gpu;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. That however requires the CUDA runtime to be available at compile-time which is what I originally wanted to avoid. These days however CUDA is much more widely available, so the original requirements have changed and now we assume that users know they have a GPU and that that they need the CUDA toolkit to use it.