# Program to check CUDA presence needs CUDA?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, cuda

I wrote a simple application that checks if NVIDIA CUDA is available on the computer. It simply displays *true* if a CUDA-capable device is found.

I send the app to a second PC, and the application didn't run - a dialog box showed up that *cudart.dll* was not found. I want to check if CUDA is present and it requires CUDA to do that :)

I am using CUDA 5.0, VS2012, VC++11, Windows 7.

**Can I compile the application in a way, that all CUDA libraries are inside the executable?**

---

So the scenario is:

1. My app is compiled & sent to a computer
2. The computer can:

   1. be running windows, linux (my app is compatible with the system)
   2. have a gpu or not
   3. have an nvidia gpu or not
   4. have CUDA installed or not
3. My app should return `true` only if 2.3 and 2.4 are positive (GPU with CUDA)

Comment: That would be static-linking. Why not dynamically link them? Also, you could check for the presence of cudart.dll before you link to it.

Comment: I want to have one executable (or one DLL that is a plugin to some framework). I dont want to send 2 files. Correct me if im wrong, but lack of cudart.dll does not mean that no CUDA-GPU is present.. do NVIDIA graphic drivers (for regular users) containt CUDA libs?

Comment: I'm confused - are you wanting to ensure (or check for) availability of the CUDA runtime library, or availability of CUDA-capable hardware, or both? (As far as I know, the latter depends on the former).

Comment: actually - both, since CUDA-hardware is useless w/o CUDA runtime.. BUT the presence of runtime does not mean a GPU is compatible (emulation is permitted)

Comment: `cudart.dll` is a file that anybody could install on their machine. it has no inherent relation to the hardware installed on your system. in order to use CUDA you will need both hardware *and* the library (you currently only check wheter you have the hardward, not the software)

Comment: @Xlaudius: CUDA hardwards *isn't* "useless" without the CUDA runtime. The CUDA driver API can be used to run CUDA code without the need for the runtime API, and the driver API library ships with the driver on all Windows platforms. It sounds like you are conflating two things with one in your question - how to detect the presence of a valid runtime API library, and then how to detect for hardware. The first answer is probably delay loading the runtime API library and handling what happens when it fails.

Comment: @talonmies you are probably right. How to check both of those?

Answer (score 6):

As an opening comment, I think the order and number of steps in your edit is incorrect. It should be:

1. Programs starts and attempts to load the runtime API library
2. If the runtime library is present, attempt to use it to enumerate devices.

If step 1 fails, you do not have the necessary runtime support, and CUDA cannot be used. If 2 fails, there is not a compatible driver and GPU present in the system and CUDA cannot be used. If they both pass, you are good to go.

In step 1 you want to use something like [`dlopen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) on Linux and handle the return status. On Windows, you probably want to use the [DLL delay loading mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/151kt790.aspx) (Sorry, not a Windows programmer, can't tell you more than that).

In both cases, if the library loads, then fetch the address of `cudaGetDeviceCount` via the appropriate host OS API and call it. That tells you whether there are compatible GPUs which can be enumerated. What you do after you find an apparently usable GPU is up to you. I would check for compute status and try establishing a context on it. That will ensure that a fully functional runtime/driver combination is present and everything works.

Comment: OK, so effectively first try to load the lib myself as a sanity check and only then call CUDA functions that themselves call/open the library? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Almost. You load the library yourself, then you need to fetch the function(s) you need from the library yourself, then setup the calls and execute them. There are examples of how to do this in the links I gave you in my answer.

Comment: So if I need `cudaMalloc` I have to fetch it myself? And fetch all 20 other functions I need?

Comment: @Xlaudius: You were asking about a "simple application that checks if NVIDIA CUDA is available on the computer. It simply displays true if a CUDA-capable device is found." I would not suggest using this for a complete application. Just have this little code self load the library, and try and enumerate the device. If you can, then fork your real application, because you know it will run OK because you have the necessary driver and hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Linking to a different post on stackoverflow: [detecting-nvidia-gpus-without-cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828468/detecting-nvidia-gpus-without-cuda) 
 This shows the whole sequence to check if the cuda api is available and accessible.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using only the software there is no reliable way to ensure that a GPU is Cuda-capable or not, especially if we consider that Cuda is a driver-based technology and for the OS Cuda doesn't exist if the driver says that Cuda doesn't exist.

I think that the best way to do this is the old fashion way, consider checking this [simple web page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) and you will get a much more reliable answer.

Comment: @talonmies and if the user is using the wrong driver ... you will never know :) Never assume that the user knows what he is doing or how his own pc is supposed to be configured, never.

Comment: Of course you will know. *If* the runtime API library is present, but there is no hardware or a driver mismatch, it will return an error telling you what is wrong, If the driver library isn't there, there is no driver. User library loading can be used to explicitly check for all these possibilities. I know because I have done it in self deploying CUDA applications for HPC clusters, where you have no idea in advance what state a node in the cluster is before your application is dropped onto the node.

Answer (score 0):

create a plugin for your application that dynamically links to the relevant CUDA-libraries and performs the check.

then try loading the plugin and run it's check.

- if the plugin fails to load, then you don't have the CUDA-libraries installed, so you can assume `False`
- if the plugin succeeds to load, then you have CUDA-libs installed and can perform the check, whether the hardware supports CUDA as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a late andditional answer:

I am struggling with the same problem (detecting cuda installation without using it) and my solution so far is

- ensuring `LoadLibraryA("nvcuda.dll") != nullptr` (tells you pretty much only if there is an nvidia card installed, though)
- checking for environment variable CUDA_PATH (or in my case, CUDA_PATH_V8_0), since that seems to be set by the cuda installation: `const char * szCuda8Path = std::getenv("CUDA_PATH_V8_0");` (must be != nullptr)

Answer (score -1):

Use [`cudaGetDeviceCount()`](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__DEVICE_g665468e8cb33be42434f11bee2684ec9.html) to know if the computer is CUDA-capable.

[According to this thread](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/397413/linking-cuda-staticly/), you cannot statically link `cudart.dll`.

There are workarounds: embed the CUDA runtime as a resource in your executable, then extract it when your program runs, then dynamically link.

You can also use [`nvidia-smi`](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-system-management-interface) to see if CUDA is installed on a machine.

Comment: in order to use `cudaSomeFunction` I need to be sure that `cudart.dll` (or else - app crashes) is present. And how to do that?